# Call to undefined function get_header() in index.php

Tags: errors, headers

I am trying to create a theme.

I created a `header.php` file and call this file  in `index.php` using

```
<?php get_header();?>
```

When I try to run my index.php file it shows this error:

> Call to undefined function `get_header()`

What could be wrong?

Comment: Show here your header.php code and index.php code

Comment: How you tried to "run" that index.php file  ....... ?? Did you made a style.css in the theme folder and tried to activate the theme from dashboard  ??

Comment: Did you created an index.php inside the theme folder ? If not then please see the answer by Rarst ......

Answer (score 2):

WordPress theme templates are not meant to be executed directly. They are loaded by WordPress core (after appropriate environment had been set up) according to [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Answer (score 1):

> Generally this happens when someone has mistakenly put index.php from
>   a theme in the WP install folder, where it overwrites the index.php
>   that is the main WordPress file.
>   Download WordPress again, and take the one file, index.php from its
>   root folder, replacing the file you now have as index.php

[source](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-to-undefined-function-get_header-i)